# Print out a char at user-chosen index x86_64

Tags: assembly, x86-64

```
extern printf
extern scanf

section .data
inputnumber db "%ld", 0
inputstring db "%s", 0 ,0
outputnumber db "%ld, ", 0
outputstring db "%s", 0 ,0


section .bss
number resq 1
string resb 124
counter resq 1
print resb 12

section .text
global main

main:
    mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
    push rbp
    
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, inputnumber
    mov rsi, number
    call scanf
    
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, inputstring
    mov rsi, string
    call scanf
    
    mov rdi, number
    mov rsi, string
    mov rbp, print
    
    mov dword [counter], 1
  
    call index
    
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, outputnumber
    mov rsi, [number]
    call printf
    
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, outputstring
    mov rsi, rbp
    call printf
    
     pop rbp
     ret

index:
    .counterInc:
    
    lodsb
   
    cmp rdi, [counter]
    
    je .correctIndex
    
    inc dword [counter]
    
    jmp .counterInc
    
    
    .correctIndex:
    mov byte [rbp-1], dl
    stosb
    ret
```

I decided to practice some assembly to get more insight on how the programming languages work at low level. I made some simple additions programs and print outs and I saw an idea for printing out a single char at a chosen location that the user inputs. I used the C functions (scanf, printf) to get user input and print out. The logic behind what I wrote is, that the function .counterInc increases the counter till it reaches the same value as our chosen index and while that is happening I call the function lodsb which if i understand correctly increments RSI by 1 everytime it loops and stores the current char in AL. When it reaches the same value as the user input it jumps to .correctIndex where we mov the char from al to the "print" variable. When I run the program all it does is crash. Can anyone point me in the right direction since I only started doing assembly last week and all of this is very new to me and I'm still struggling with some concepts

Comment: do you have any message, what point it crashes at? please add more information.

Comment: @Ruli it does not have any message. I use SASM to run the code and it only says it crashes

Comment: Your first task is to figure out how to install and run a debugger on your system, so that you can single-step your code and see what it's doing.  Once you can do that, and look at what you are loading into registers before calling `index`, things should be a lot more clear.  You might also think about how you could fetch just the single desired character instead of walking through all the ones before it.  `lodsb/stosb` are not particularly efficient on modern machines and there's no reason to go out of your way to use them.